# Android UltimateRecyclerView Unexpected Error When Scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

When I scroll through my list (using `ultimateRecyclerView`), my apps show Unexpected Error Dialog and quit. What is wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: What's the error? Can you please add your logcat here with the question for better assistance.